# Struggling on what to write more for acceptance tests of user stories, use cases as well

Tags: software-design, use-case, acceptance-testing, user-stories

[I am not exactly clear on what an acceptance test is, is it basically information about the feature?](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_sLfWA1vu_Y2erxbGZiPn5UH959KwF6U_iWdX3XMt5o/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Ask the Product Owner "How are you going to test that this is good enough to deploy?" Everything they tell you is part of your battery of acceptance tests.

Answer (score 0):

A User Story will typically have a number of Acceptance Criteria.  They are typically written in an "As a [Role] I want [Feature] so that [Benefit]".  Writing them in this way conveys good contextual information to the development team (what they need to do, why they need to do it, and who the user is).

An [Acceptance test](https://broadek.co.uk/blog/AutomatedAcceptanceTestsChallengesAndSolutions) will verify one of the acceptance criteria on a User Story.  Your Product Owner will write the Acceptance criteria, and ideally collaborate with you as much as possible to get them running technically in Spec Flow, Fitnesse, Cucumber etc...